# How do I include run time arguments while executing a google cloud workflow in Nodejs?

Tags: google-workflows

I'm trying to include run time variables while executing a google cloud workflow. I can't find the documentation to do so unless you're using a REST API.

Here's my code that's mostly from their documentation I just get null for the arguments. I think it could be something with the second parameter it expects on createExecution named execution, but I can't figure it out.

```
const { ExecutionsClient } = require('@google-cloud/workflows');

const client = new ExecutionsClient();

const execute = () => {
  return client.createExecution(
    {
      parent: client.workflowPath('project_id', 'location', 'name'),
    },
    {
      argument: {
        users: ['info here'],
      },
    },
  );
};

module.exports = execute;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone else has this problem you pass the parameter execution to createExecution() along with parent. It's just an object and you can specify argument there which takes a string. Stringify your object and you're good to go!

```
const { ExecutionsClient } = require('@google-cloud/workflows');

const client = new ExecutionsClient();

const execute = () => {
  return client.createExecution({
    parent: client.workflowPath('', '', ''),
    execution: {
      argument: JSON.stringify({
        users: [],
      }),
    },
  });
};

module.exports = execute;
```